# How to give uniqid/hash value to saved file in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a function that let a user to upload and save the file to the system and show the file in the table. The problem is whenever there is a duplicate name it will not appear in the database and the file will not show in the table. As the title says, how to give uniqid/hash value to saved file?

Here is my code:

```
public function updatepekerjaan(Request $request, $id){
        $pekerjaan = Pekerjaan::find($id);
        $pekerjaan->update($request->all());
        if($request->hasFile('gambar')){
            $request->file('gambar')->move('gambarpekerjaan/', $request->file('gambar')->getClientOriginalName());
            $pekerjaan->gambar = $request->file('gambar')->getClientOriginalName();
            $pekerjaan->save();


            // $file = request()->file('gambar');
            // $extension = $file->getClientOriginalName();
            // $destination = 'gambarpekerjaan/';
            // $filename = uniqid() . '.' . $extension;
            // $file->move($destination, $filename);
            // $new_file = new Pekerjaan();
            // $new_file->gambar = $filename;
            // $new_file->save(); << doesn't work
        }
        
        return redirect()->route('datapekerjaan')->with('message','Pekerjaan Berhasil diupdate!');
    }
```

I have also tried changing the *getClientOriginalName* into *hashName* but it doesn't work

```
$pekerjaan->update($request->all());
        if($request->hasFile('gambar')){
            $request->file('gambar')->move('gambarpekerjaan/', $request->file('gambar')->hashName());
            $pekerjaan->gambar = $request->file('gambar')->hashName();
            $pekerjaan->save();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the timestamp to generate unique filename

```
if($request->hasFile('gambar')){        
    $fileExtension = $request->file('gambar')->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $basename = uniqid(time());
    $filename = $basename.'.'.$fileExtension;
    
    $request->file('gambar')->move('gambarpekerjaan/', $filename);
    $pekerjaan->gambar = $filename;
    $pekerjaan->save();
```